# How do declarative and object environment records relate to "var", "let", and "const"?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-scope

I am trying to dig deeper into javascript, and although I have found explanations on the differences between "var", "let", and "const" as well as explanations on ES6 "environment records" (declarative vs. object), I am still lost why the following code works the way it does when I type it into the Google Chrome Browser Console:

```
var a = 2;
let b = 4;

console.log(window.a); // 2
console.log(window.b); // undefined

console.log(a); // 2
console.log(b); // 4
```

If `console.log(b)` prints 4, but `console.log(window.b)` prints `undefined`, then what scope is `b` defined in?

I understand that when `var` is used outside of a function, it creates an `undefined` variable in the global scope.  What I don't understand is what happens when `let` or `const` is used outside of a function as in the example above?

I assume based on other answers that this behavior has something to do with ES6 environment records, but when I read the [reference book](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-environment-records), it truly does not make sense to me.

Can someone explain this in slightly simpler terms than in that reference book?

Comment: I think the dup is pretty much a match, but to elaborate a little, essentially there is the global object scope, and the global lexical scope, and `let` creates a binding attached to the global lexical scope, and `window` only accesses the global object scope. The global object scope is the outer-most, and the global lexical is the single scope nested inside it, and all other scopes for modules and functions and things end up inside that one.

Comment: For an answer I believe you can look at the specification under `Runtime Semantics: EvalDeclarationInstantation`(https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-evaldeclarationinstantiation) specifically 5.a.i.2 which states *"NOTE: eval will not create a global var declaration that would be shadowed by a global lexical declaration."*